# How to analyze this sentence’s logic: “If it rains, I'll take an umbrella.”

Tags: sentence-meaning

A person was asked to analyze the following sentence, but couldn't answer even after some searching.  They did not understand that this was a logic puzzle.

> If it rains, I'll take an umbrella.

How would one analyze the truth table of the logic of this sentence?

Comment: Note this Q/A was *inspired by* another question (closed as of now).  This was reinterpreted and given a context that allows it to be answered.

Comment: A corollary of [Murphy's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law#Other_variations_on_Murphy.27s_law) says, "If I don't take my umbrella, it'll rain."

Comment: @StoneyB, Question added.

Comment: @jr But a further corollary is: If you leave your umbrella at home to make it rain, it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a classic example used in logic.  **See Google Search:** [`"if p then q" rains umbrella`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22if+p+then+q%22+rains+umbrella)

> If it rains, **(then)** I'll take an umbrella.

If p then q.
p = it rains
q = I'll take an umbrella.

**Statement is true or false accordingly:**

- **True:** It rains and I take my umbrella.
- **False:** It rains and I don't take my umbrella.
- **True:** It doesn't rain and I take my umbrella.
- **True:** It doesn't rain and I don't take my umbrella.

**Note the abbreviated rule:**

- **True:** It doesn't rain. (It doesn't matter if I take my umbrella.)

**Note the equivalent statement:** "I take my umbrella OR it doesn't rain." (Non-exclusive "or")

---

**Also note the *alternative logic* of [Murphey's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law):** *A corollary of Murphy's Law says, "If I don't take my umbrella, it'll rain."* (Credit to @J.R.)

Comment: I think the equivalent should be: *"If I don't take my umbrella, it won't rain."*

Comment: That logic's wrong. It has all kinds of unpleasant side effects. For example, if you say "*It's not true that if it rains, I'll take my umbrella*" according to the meaning you've given there, it means "*It **will** rain and I won't take my umbrella*" and this is obviously not what that sentence means!

Comment: My answer is more "correct" relative to the question-as-it-is, and I wrote the question specifically to answer it.  However, @StoneyB's answer provides a fantastic alternative answer.

Answer (score 5):

Behold the difference between Logic and Language.

In Logic, as demonstrated by CoolHandLouis, a conditional is a Proposition of a peculiar sort: *p ⇒ q*. This declares a truth-relationship between two Propositions, *p* and *q*, each of which is either True (T) or False (F), and the truth of the conditional Proposition is represented in a Truth Table such as that CoolHandLouis presents.

In Language, however, a conditional is not a Proposition but an Utterance. An Utterance *may* express a logical Proposition, but most do not; they express not relationships between Propositions but relationships between unactualized Eventualities. Such Eventualities are not current at the time of Utterance, and consequently they can have no truth-value; and in many cases, such as counterfactual conditionals, they can *never* have truth-value. They are neither True nor False but actualized or unactualized. And even in those cases where the Eventualities are actualized or conclusively not actualized, these outcomes do not necessarily entail a judgment of Truth or Falsity of the Utterance; for non-Propositional Utterances are Promises or Predictions, which are likewise neither True nor False but actualized or unactualized.

In the instant case, if I promise that if it rains I'll bring an umbrella, and in the event it **does** rain and I **don’t** bring an umbrella, my soaked wife will not chide me for uttering a falsehood, but for breaking a promise. And if it does **not** rain and I don’t bring an umbrella, she will not praise me for uttering a truth; she will say “It’s a good thing it didn’t rain.”

For more info, see [conditional sentences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_sentence).

Comment: This is fantastic! I see you're pointing to some modern philosophy of language that is not typically discussed.  Perhaps this would make a better question in the philosophy forum...

Comment: @CoolHandLouis Oh, I dunno nuffin bout birthin no philosophy :) This is straight LitCrit, out of Philip Sidney, moved from poetics into performatives.

Comment: @!StoneyB, My answer is more "correct" relative to the question-as-it-is, but it's also rather trite and "findable-anywhereable". I would prefer to reword the question and edit yours into a two-part answer contrasting the simple predicate-logic answer with the utterance/eventuality answer and mark that as "correct". I could reword the question, add my "simple" answer into your answer, and then mark your answer correct.  May I have a shot at this?  You could simply revert or further edit (both question and answer) as needed.

Comment: @CoolHandLouis Go for it; but take what you like of mine and meld it into yours instead, and I'll delete mine when it's over. ... I think the key  thing from an ELL perspective is that the tense rules change: an actualization conditional requires that the protasis be temporally prior to the apodosis, while an inference conditional has no such constraint: you may argue from the truth of an anterior fact to the truth of a posterior fact.

Comment: @!StoneyB, Thanks!  This is a backburner project for me and there's absolutely no expected timeline on this. It will require me to dig deeper into the theory you presented.  I'll notify you if/when done to solicit your review.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to leave things as they are!  I just added the link "for more info", if ok with you.